# After Android 11 Update an error: .apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, samsung-mobile

I've made a simple application for testing, one Form with one Button. (Samsung Note 10) Until 17.01.2021 have worked properly. There were a Software Update at this time, and I Noticed, that this applocation is not working. I tried to reinstall from Delphi 10.3, but the following Debugger Exception appeared: .apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11).
When I press the Break the Debugger takes me to the System:

```
function UnicodeFromLocaleChars(const LocaleName: _AnsiStr; Flags: Cardinal;
 LocaleStr: _PAnsiChr; LocaleStrLen: Integer; UnicodeStr: PWideChar;
 UnicodeStrLen: Integer): Integer; overload;

var
Err: UErrorCode;
 Conv: PUConverter;
 NSubs: Int32;
begin
 Result := 0;
 if LocaleName = 'UTF-8' then
 begin
   Err := U_ZERO_ERROR;
   ***u_strFromUTF8WithSub(UnicodeStr, UnicodeStrLen, Result, LocaleStr, LocaleStrLen, UChar32('?'), NSubs, Err);***
   if (UnicodeStrLen > 0) and (Err > 0) then
```

I tried to Ignore, but the Application not works also in this case.

I tried on other Android 10 devices without software update, it works properly with the same options.

Can you give me some suggestion, what can I do, to work on this device?

Thanks for you Answere!

Comment: The only way to fix the issue is to update to 10.4 Delphi.  I have found that Delphi 11 has issues with the Debugger and highly suggest not updating to Delphi 11 yet.  I can't update to Delphi 11.1.5 because I can't afford the $2000 upgrade costs. When you run out of money, you run out of help with Delphi. "This is a gentle reminder that your Embarcadero maintenance subscription is already expired. Please understand that there is 100%-150% reinstatement fee after the grace period." Source: Saba Khan - saba.khan@embarcadero.com